# Can i store a SqlLite DB into an (old) ESP32? (not using SD card)

Tags: esp32

I would like to know if it is possible to store a (little, basic) SqlLite DataBase (or of any other type) into the (old) ESP32.
I don't want to use an SD card for that (for which I already know it is possible).
Thanks in advance for any hint on this

Comment: Sure, you can store it. You can store anything you like, size permitting, it's just a file after all. But I assume you actually want to *use* it from the ESP32 too?

Comment: @Majenko sure! ;-) i would load data "once" on programming the ESP32, and then "just" read it to take decissions and drive the program on different settings.

Comment: Then a database file is probably overkill. You could just use a simple text file for that.

Comment: @Majenko thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these two post to be a useful answer to my question:

- [ESP32: Best way to store data frequently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780850/esp32-best-way-to-store-data-frequently)
- [Sqlite3 Library for ESP32 Arduino Core](https://www.hackster.io/arun/sqlite3-library-for-esp32-arduino-core-a76ad1)

Comment: It could be really educating and clarifying if the downvoter would shine to explain why he downvoted... downvoting without an explanation may be considered impolite and unsmart...

Comment: Possibly because it mostly consists of links.  You can always add more details on how they helped.  Broadly you can make the answer more useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can - or you can certainly store it. ESP32 can use its flash as a filesystem (SPIFFS, LittleFS, FAT, etc) so you can store whatever data you like on there.

Whether the SQLite library can work with that file is another matter though, and is something you would have to explore yourself.

However for your use case using a database file is a bit silly. If all you want is some pre-defined runtime settings then all you really need is a simple text file. Maybe something like an INI file (key=value pairs) would be plenty for your needs, and pretty simple to parse without any libraries.